# Comparing files and their properties

Tags: shell, text-processing, scripting, files, diff

I get information of a certain set of files in my mail  every day, which looks like this:

```
58623208 Sep 14 20:08 blbn_blfbe_drv
57904920 Sep 14 19:54 blbn_cycmn
55814208 Sep 14 06:02 clsa_Upd
38912000 Sep 14 19:12 cs_chgpp
41107456 Sep 14 19:17 csmRFbe
39403520 Sep 14 19:09 csmUAddAct
39235584 Sep 14 19:20 csmUAddSub
```

... and so on, for about 60 files.

Now, I need to compare all these files, one by one, with the existing files to make sure that all the files are are found matching.

`filename`, `timestamp`, `date`, and `size` are the things should be matching.

Is there any way to automate it?

I was thinking about using either `comm` or `diff`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you have GNU date, with the `-d` option:

```
while read size mon day time filename; do
    if [[ ! -f "$filename" ]]; then
        echo "ERROR: no such file: $filename" >&2
    else
        filesize=$(stat -c %s "$filename")
        if [[ "$size" != "$filesize" ]]; then
            echo "ERROR: size mismatch: $filename" >&2
        else
            filetime=$(date -d "$(stat -c %y "$filename")" "+%b %d %H:%M")
            if [[ "$mon $day $time" != "$filetime" ]]; then
                echo "ERROR: date mismatch: $filename" >&2
            fi
        fi
    fi
done
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that all new files are in (or can be moved to) new/ and all old files are in old/ directories, you can use 'diff -ur old/ new/' to see the differences in files between the directories.

If you don't care about the nature of the differences, only the *fact* that some files are different then use grep to filter the output - but you will lose the exit code from diff (1 = differences found).  Instead you can use the exit code from grep (1 = no regexp matches found, which you can interpret to mean that all files are the same).

e.g. i generated some text files in old and new (just rubbish containing directory listings of /bin, /sbin, and /etc).  then i edited new/baz and deleted some lines:

```
$ ls -l new old
new:
total 28
-rw-r--r-- 1 cas cas 11063 Sep 15 15:27 baz
-rw-r--r-- 1 cas cas 14529 Sep 15 15:25 foo

old:
total 20
-rw-r--r-- 1 cas cas  6843 Sep 15 15:24 bar
-rw-r--r-- 1 cas cas 12025 Sep 15 15:24 baz
```

first, compare the two dirs:

```
$ diff -ur old new | egrep '^(Only|diff)'
Only in old: bar
diff -ur old/baz new/baz
Only in new: foo
$ echo $?
0
```

here you can see the exit code when the src and dst dirs are the same (or have exactly the same content)

```
$ diff -ur old old | egrep '^(Only|diff)'
$ echo $?
1
```

you could also use cmp, but it can only match individual files, it can't recursively check two directories for differences.  you'd have to write a for loop wrapper around it, and you'd have to take into account files that exist only in new but not in old.  easier to use diff.